# Unable to access properties on Typed React Redux store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

I been searching up and down google, official docs, stack overflow for a way to access my Redux store, from a React functional component (Typescript). In theory this should be easy to do with the various guides out there, but no matter what I do I keep getting undefined errors. I am able to get the store object with a custom typed selector hook and console.log it and see the properties as expected, but when accessing them, I am still getting access denied. Strangely enough, the only way I was able to get this to work was stringifying and then parsing the store object as JSON. While that did work that is not ideal and I trying to figure out the proper way to achieve this. I believe I have narrowed it down to some Typing issues. I should also note that I have no issues dispatching actions to update the values in the store. I may not be explaining my scenario well, so here is my code and examples to better demonstrate:

**Setup**

/src/state/action-types/index.ts:

```
export enum ActionType {
    UPDATE_LOADING_STATUS = 'update_loading_status',
    UPDATE_ONLINE_STATUS = 'update_online_status',
    UPDATE_APP_LAUNCH_COUNT = 'update_app_launch_count',
}
```

/src/state/actions/index.ts:

```
import { ActionType } from '../action-types'

export interface UpdateLoadingStatus {
    type: ActionType.UPDATE_LOADING_STATUS
    payload: boolean
}

export interface UpdateOnlineStatus {
    type: ActionType.UPDATE_ONLINE_STATUS
    payload: boolean
}

export interface UpdateAppLaunchCount {
    type: ActionType.UPDATE_APP_LAUNCH_COUNT
}

export type Action = UpdateLoadingStatus | UpdateOnlineStatus | UpdateAppLaunchCount
```

/src/state/reducers/AppStateReducer.ts:

```
import produce from 'immer'
import { ActionType } from '../action-types'
import { Action } from '../actions'

interface AppState {
    isLoading: boolean
    isOnline: boolean
    isAppVisible: boolean | null
    entitlements: string[] | null
    persona: string | null
    theme: 'light' | 'dark' | 'default'
    appLaunchCount: number
}

const initialState: AppState = {
    isLoading: true,
    isOnline: false,
    isAppVisible: null,
    entitlements: null,
    persona: null,
    theme: 'default',
    appLaunchCount: 0,
}

export const reducer = produce((state: AppState = initialState, action: Action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ActionType.UPDATE_LOADING_STATUS:
            state.isLoading = action.payload
            return state
        case ActionType.UPDATE_ONLINE_STATUS:
            state.isOnline = action.payload
            return state
        case ActionType.UPDATE_APP_LAUNCH_COUNT:
            state.appLaunchCount = state.appLaunchCount + 1
            return state
        default:
            return state
    }
}, initialState)
```

/src/state/index.ts:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { reducer as AppStateReducer } from './reducers/AppStateReducer'

export const reducers = combineReducers({
    appstate: AppStateReducer,
})

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof reducers>
```

/src/state/store.ts:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import { reducer } from './reducers'
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension'

export const store = createStore(
    reducer,
    {
        isLoading: true,
        isOnline: false,
        isAppVisible: null,
        entitlements: null,
        persona: null,
        theme: 'default',
        appLaunchCount: 0,
    },
    composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk))
)
```

/src/index.tsx:

```
import * as ReactDom from 'react-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { store } from './state/store'
import { App } from './components/App'

ReactDom.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.querySelector('#root')
)
```

/src/components/App.tsx:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useActions } from '../hooks/useActions'
import { useTypedSelector } from '../hooks/useTypedSelector'
import { RootState } from '../state'

export const App: React.FC = () => {
    const { updateLoadingStatus, updateOnlineStatus, updateAppLaunchCount } = useActions()

    const stateA = useTypedSelector((state) => state)

    console.log(state)

    return (
        ...content...
    )
}
```

src/hooks/useTypedSelector.ts

```
import { useSelector, TypedUseSelectorHook } from 'react-redux'
import { RootState } from '../state'

export const useTypedSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector
```

**Examples**

Ok this is where the fun begins.

If I do this:
`const stateA = useTypedSelector((state) => state)`
I get the overall store object in the console.log:

```
{isLoading: false, isOnline: true, isAppVisible: null, entitlements: null, persona: null, …}
appLaunchCount: 2
entitlements: null
isAppVisible: null
isLoading: false
isOnline: true
persona: null
theme: "default"
__proto__: Object
```

But if I try to do:
`const stateA = useTypedSelector((state) => state.appLaunchCount)`
I get this error, *even though the output is logged properly*.

```
Property 'appLaunchCount' does not exist on type 'CombinedState<{ appstate: AppState; }>'
```

I was still getting an output logged on the store object, I had an the idea to stringify and parse that state object, and then I was able to access the properties:
`const stateB = JSON.parse( useTypedSelector(( state ) => JSON.stringify( state )))`

However, the documentation I find online says should be able to access properties like this:
`const stateC= useTypedSelector((state) => state.appstate.appLaunchCount)`, but instead I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appLaunchCount' of undefined
```

I suspect it may be an issue with the shape or Type of the store, but I am not sure what else I can try. Last clue I have is that if I hover over the RootState object is this:

```
(alias) type RootState = EmptyObject & {
    appstate: AppState;
}
```

Not sure that empty object is about and/or if it preventing me from accessing the properties. Please assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a mismatch in your reducer file and your store setup file.

In `src/state/index.ts:`, you have:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { reducer as AppStateReducer } from './reducers/AppStateReducer'

export const reducers = combineReducers({
    appstate: AppStateReducer,
})

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof reducers>
```

and in `src/state/store.ts`, you have:

```
import { reducer } from './reducers'
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension'

export const store = createStore(
    reducer,
    // etc
)
```

If you look *very* carefully... you imported **`reducer`** into your store file. That's the individual "app state" slice reducer, *not* your combined "root reducer".  But, the TS type you're exporting *is* the combined root reducer.

So, you set up the types correctly, but got the runtime behavior doing something else.

Change `import { reducer }`  to `import { reducers }`, and fix what you're passing to the store to match, and it should work okay.

As a side note: you should really be using [our official Redux Toolkit package](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-8-modern-redux) and following [the rest of our TS setup guidelines](https://redux.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript).  That would completely eliminate all the "actions" files, part of the code in the reducer, and the rest of the config setup in the store file.